# PHP/SQL - Blank page for registered users for a simple registration page

Tags: php, registration

I have an assignment where I have to make a registration page in php.... I just want to keep things simple so making the form work is all I'm aiming for. I am aware of the vulnerability of sql injections/plaintext, but that's the last of my worries for now since it's a class assignment.

The script below works as far as inserting new users/passwords, but if there's an existing user, the page is blank and doesn't give a warning. I'm looking for help in giving the error "Sorry, this user already exists" shown on the screen (or something).

Thanks :D.

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '////////');
define('DB_USER','/////////');
define('DB_PASSWORD','///////////');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

function NewUser() { $userName = $_POST['user']; $password = $_POST['pass']; $query = "INSERT INTO UserName (userName,pass) VALUES ('$userName','$password')"; $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); if($data) { echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; } } function SignUp() { if(!empty($_POST['user']))  { 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 

if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query))) 
{ newuser(); } 
else { echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER..."; } } } if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignUp(); } ?>
```

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: $5 says someone comments about sql injection even though you're already aware.

Comment: your school still teaches mysql_* - find a better school

Comment: ^ Basically my professor taught nothing but expects us to learn this on our own without his help :D.

Comment: ^^ After using error_reporting, it shows: "The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead. I would be guessing I use mysqli_connect instead? :>

Comment: Well, assuming your validation in IF statement `if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)))` is NOT true, it will execute the undefined function. Are you really sure there is nothing in error report? You defined `NewUser` function and then you try to call `newuser`? Besides, this IF statement has a closing "extra" parenthesis. Check your code, please and inform what kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Its really important check your `php_error_log` or Add **error reporting** into the TOP of your file.

```
<?php 
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

There is an extra closing parenthesis and you are calling an undefined function.
Assuming these are the errors, fix then with:

```
if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    NewUser();
} 
else {
     echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER..."; 
}
```

- Also, consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Thanks to @bcesars for the extra parenthesis fix. I thought there was something odd with the count.
2. After, I came up with a problem where the "This user already exists" error pops up ONLY if the user and pass matches the same one in the database. If I use a different password, the info is still inserted into the database.

Solution: 
Remove

```
 AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'
```

from

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

So far it works. I'm still new into this whole database/php thing so thanks for bearing with me ♥

Comment: Nice. Glad I can help you. I'll be happy if you accept my answer. =)